Elegant way to handle a series of interpolation functions
In this post, I wrote a piece of code that can bypass singularities in numerical solutions of the first type of Painlevé ODE. The code is as follows
soluv[x0_, u0_, v0_, xmin_ : -10, xmax_ : 10] := 
  Reap@First@
    NDSolve[{6/v[x] + x u[x]^4 v[x] + 2 Derivative[1][u][x] == 4, 
      6 + x u[x]^4 v[x]^2 == 6 v[x] + u[x] Derivative[1][v][x], 
      u[x0] == u0, v[x0] == v0, 
      WhenEvent[
       Abs[u[x]] + Abs[v[x]] > 10^3 || Chop[x - xmax] == 0 || 
        Chop[x - xmin] == 0, Sow[{x, u[x], v[x]}]; 
       "StopIntegration"]}, {u, v}, {x, xmin, xmax}];

soly[x0_, y0_, yp0_, xmin_ : -10, xmax_ : 10] := 
  Reap@First@
    NDSolve[{y''[x] == 6 y[x]^2 + x, y[x0] == y0, y'[x0] == yp0, 
      WhenEvent[
       Abs[y[x]] > 10^5 || Chop[x - xmax] == 0 || Chop[x - xmin] == 0,
        Sow[{x, y[x], y'[x]}]; "StopIntegration"]}, 
     y, {x, xmin, xmax}];

ytouv[x0_, y0_, yp0_] := {x0, 2 y0/yp0, yp0^2/(4 y0^3)};
ytouv[x_List] := ytouv @@ x;
uvtoy[x0_, u0_, v0_] := {x0, 1/(u0^2 v0), 2/(u0^3 v0)};
uvtoy[x_List] := uvtoy @@ x;

PainleveSolve[x0_, y0_, yp0_, xmin_ : -10, xmax_ : 10, sy_ : sy, 
  suv_ : suv] :=
 Block[{imin, imax},
  Clear[sy, suv];
  sy[1] = soly[x0, y0, yp0];
  imax = 
   First@First@
     Last@Reap@
       Do[If[Chop[sy[i][[2, 1, 2, 1]] - xmax] >= 0, Sow[i]; Break[]]; 
        suv[i] = soluv[Sequence @@ ytouv@sy[i][[2, 1, 2]], xmin, xmax];
        sy[i + 1] = 
         soly[Sequence @@ uvtoy@suv[i][[2, 1, 2]], xmin, 
          xmax + 10^6];, {i, 1, 10^6}];
  imin = 
   First@First@
     Last@Reap@
       Do[If[Chop[sy[-i + 1][[2, 1, 1, 1]] - xmin] <= 0, Sow[-i + 1]; 
         Break[]];
        suv[-i] = 
         soluv[Sequence @@ ytouv@sy[-i + 1][[2, 1, 1]], xmin, xmax];
        sy[-i] = 
         soly[Sequence @@ uvtoy@suv[-i][[2, 1, 1]], xmin, 
          xmax + 10^6];, {i, 0, 10^6}];
  Print[{imin, imax}];
  Table[sy[i][[1, 1]], {i, imin, imax}]]

The function PainleveSolve returns the numerical solution of the first type of Painlevé ODE $y''(x)=6y(x)^2+x$. For example, PainleveSolve[0, 1, 0, -10, 10] gives the solution with boundary condition $y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$ in area $-10<x<10$,

and the plot is shown as
sol = PainleveSolve[0, 1, 0, -10, 10];
Show[Plot[y[x] /. #, {x, Sequence @@ #[[2]]["Domain"][[1]]}] & /@ sol,
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-20, 40}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> True]



My question is: is there an elegant way to handle these series interpolation functions?
Can these interpolation functions be integrated into one function?

You can construct a Piecewise function from them: combinedSol =   Function[Evaluate@Piecewise[Table[{s[#], s["Domain"][[1, 1]] <= # <= s["Domain"][[1, 2]]}, {s, sol[[All, 2]]}], Undefined]] Is this something you want to achieve?
